# Value behind decimal place float point value

Tags: c, if-statement, floating-point

Writing if statement to identify if float variable holds value behind decimal place.

Example code:

```
AAA = 123.456

if( AAA has value behind decimal = true)

{

        printf("true")

}

// ...or user input changes value of AAA...

AAA = 123.000


if( AAA has value behind decimal = true)

{

        printf("false")

}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double param, fractpart, intpart;

    param = 123.456;
    fractpart = modf(param , &intpart);
    if (fractpart != 0.0) {
        printf("true\n");
    } else {
        printf("false\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that numerical errors arise during computations due to round-off errors and truncation, e.g.:

```
0.11 - (0.07 + 0.04) != 0.0
```

You can control those round-off errors (adjust the `EPSILON` value according your scale):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define EPSILON 0.00000000001

int almost_zero(double x)
{
    return fabs(x) < EPSILON;
}

int main(void)
{

    double param, fractpart, intpart;

    param = 0.11 - (0.07 + 0.04);
    fractpart = modf(param , &intpart);
    if (!almost_zero(fractpart)) {
        printf("true\n");
    } else {
        printf("false\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `fmod(AAA,1.0f)`

Answer (score 0):

If it fits in a long: `if ((long) AAA == AAA) ...`